# How to prevent keyboard from overlaping controls in windows store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

One of my pages in a windows store app, has some TextBox for the user to fill in, but when the keyboard shows, it hides some of the TextBoxs behind it.

is there any way to pull the page up when keyboard shows? or at least center the app on the focused textbox.

this is one of the XAML pages i have

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <common:StringToValidityConverter x:Key="StringToValidityConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource SubHeaderStyle}">
        <Image Source="/Images/Contract/Billing.png" Style="{StaticResource SubHeaderImageStyle}" />
        <TextBlock x:Uid="Billing" Style="{StaticResource SubHeaderTextStyle}" />
        <Button Click="OnResetButtonClicked" Style="{StaticResource ResetButtonStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock x:Uid="AccountNumber" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding AccountNumber, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"
                 common:TextBoxBehavior.Validity="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource StringToValidityConverter}}" />

        <TextBlock x:Uid="BillingPeriod" Grid.Column="3" />
        <input:SfDatePicker Grid.Column="4" Value="{Binding BillingPeriod, Mode=TwoWay}" />

        <TextBlock x:Uid="AccountCategory" Grid.Row="1" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding AccountCategory, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"
                 common:TextBoxBehavior.Validity="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource StringToValidityConverter}}" />

        <TextBlock x:Uid="CompanyName" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding CompanyName, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"
                 common:TextBoxBehavior.Validity="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource StringToValidityConverter}}" />

        <TextBlock x:Uid="CompanyType" Grid.Row="2" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding CompanyType, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"
                 common:TextBoxBehavior.Validity="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource StringToValidityConverter}}" />

        <TextBlock x:Uid="VatNumber" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding VatNumber, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"
                 common:TextBoxBehavior.Validity="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource StringToValidityConverter}}" />

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock x:Uid="RegistrationNumber" />
            <TextBlock Text=" 1" />
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding RegistrationNumber1, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"
                 common:TextBoxBehavior.Validity="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource StringToValidityConverter}}" />

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock x:Uid="RegistrationNumber" />
            <TextBlock Text=" 2" />
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="5" Text="{Binding RegistrationNumber2, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"
                 common:TextBoxBehavior.Validity="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource StringToValidityConverter}}" />

        <TextBlock x:Uid="BusinessActivity" Grid.Row="4" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding BusinessActivity, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"
                 common:TextBoxBehavior.Validity="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource StringToValidityConverter}}" />

        <TextBlock x:Uid="NumberOfEmployees" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding NumberOfEmployees, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource ShortTextBoxStyle}"
                 common:TextBoxBehavior.Validity="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource StringToValidityConverter}}" />

        <TextBlock x:Uid="Language" Grid.Row="5" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Language, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"
                 common:TextBoxBehavior.Validity="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource StringToValidityConverter}}" />

        <TextBlock x:Uid="CorrespondanceLanguage" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding CorrespondanceLanguage, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"
                 common:TextBoxBehavior.Validity="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource StringToValidityConverter}}" />

        <TextBlock x:Uid="LandlinePhone" Grid.Row="6" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LandlinePhone, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"
                 common:TextBoxBehavior.Validity="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource StringToValidityConverter}}" />

        <TextBlock x:Uid="MobilePhone" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="3" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding MobilePhone, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"
                 common:TextBoxBehavior.Validity="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource StringToValidityConverter}}" />

        <TextBlock x:Uid="EmailAddress" Grid.Row="7" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding EmailAddress, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"
                 common:TextBoxBehavior.Validity="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource StringToValidityConverter}}" />
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: And http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Keyboard-Events-Sample-866ba41c